# OpenCV - Working with pictures with a transparent background

Tags: python, opencv

I have a character. On a transparent background. I want to add glasses to him. This picture is also on a transparent background. If I use this code, then the picture is inserted with a black background.
What is the solution? thanks

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt


img = cv2.imread('pers.png')[...,::-1]
img2 = img.copy()

mask = cv2.imread('glasses.png')[...,::-1]
img2[2:(2+mask.shape[0]), 4:(4+mask.shape[1])] = mask


im = Image.fromarray(img2)
im.save("resume.png")
```

Comment: You need to extract the alpha channel from the image and multiply it with the mask image. Then put that product back into the alpha channel of the original image.

Comment: recipe: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/20780 and I'm betting this question is a duplicate @fmw42

Comment: @Christoph Rackwitz  Good suggestion. Compositing in OpenCV seems unnecessarily hard to me. Too many steps for a simple and useful operation. Glad to see your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do that in Python/OpenCV.

```
 - Read the first image (unchanged)
 - Read the second image (unchanged)
 - Extract the BGR and alpha channels from the first image 
 - Extract the BGR and alpha channels from the second image
 - Specify the offset for the second image onto the first image
 - Insert the BGR channels of the second image into a copy of the BGR channels of the first image
 - Insert the mask from the alpha channel of the second image into a black image the size of the first image
 - Combine the new mask with the alpha channel of the first image by multiplication (or using bitwise_and)
 - Blend the inserted version of the second image with the first image using the combined mask via Numpy where().
 - Save results
```

First Input:

[image]

Second Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read background image
img = cv2.imread("obama_transparent.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
ht, wd = img.shape[:2]

# read overlay image
img2 = cv2.imread("sunglasses.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
ht2, wd2 = img2.shape[:2]

# extract alpha channel as mask and base bgr images
bgr = img[:,:,0:3]
mask = img[:,:,3]
bgr2 = img2[:,:,0:3]
mask2 = img2[:,:,3]

# insert bgr2 into bgr1 at desired location and insert mask2 into black image
x = 580
y = 390

bgr2_new = bgr.copy()
bgr2_new[y:y+ht2, x:x+wd2] = bgr2

mask_new = np.zeros((ht,wd), dtype=np.uint8)
mask_new[y:y+ht2, x:x+wd2] = mask2

# combine the two masks
# either multiply or use bitwise_and
mask_combined = cv2.multiply(mask,mask_new)
mask_combined = cv2.cvtColor(mask_combined, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

# overlay the base bgr2_new image onto bgr using mask
result = np.where(mask_combined==255, bgr2_new, bgr)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('obama_transparent_glasses.jpg', result)

# display results
cv2.imshow('bgr', bgr)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('bgr2', bgr2)
cv2.imshow('mask2', mask2)
cv2.imshow('bgr2_new', bgr2_new)
cv2.imshow('mask_combined', mask_new)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: thanks! its work for this images, but not work for 24x24px images. Fior example i tried with https://i.imgur.com/IAigrkK.png and  https://i.imgur.com/WLBx3Wj.png

Comment: Works for me. What was your offset coordinates. They should be x=0, y=0. They represent where the upper left corner of the second image should be offset from the upper left corner of the first image. They are not the coordinates of where you want to glasses to be. If you need that, then you must properly offset the offsets.